# Строки одной таблицы как столбец в другой

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, linq

Допустим есть БД для хранения постов. 
Пост, как сущность в приложении может представлять из себя примерно следующий класс:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; } //Автор поста
    public string Caption { get; set; } 
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Attachment[] Attachments { get; set; } //Вложения (картинки, видео)
    public Comment[] Comments { get; set; } //Комментарии
}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; } //Автор комментария
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Attachment[] Attachments { get; set; } //Вложения (картинки, видео)
}

public class Attachment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; } //'image' или 'video'
    public string Link { get; set; } //прямая ссылка или embed
}
```

Но в БД у автора (пользователей), вложений и комментариев будут свои таблицы.

В контексте же БД в таблице поста будет храниться лишь `id` автора поста.  
Комментарии в ней не будут упоминаться, т.к., опять же, логичнее разместить столбец `post_id` в таблице комментариев и таким образом фильтровать комментарии выбранного поста.  
Вложения, скорее всего, не будут иметь единственного владельца (в отличии от комментариев), так что в таблице постов они будут как массив `id` вложений.

Как я себе представляю то, как оно должно выглядеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то при помощи LINQ и Entity Framework отправить один запрос, который вернёт полностью заполненный объект класса `Post`?

Если да, то как правильно оформить сущности и таблицы, чтобы оно работало корректно?

---

Опыта работы с БД у меня мало, так что описанное выше это не жёсткие требования задачи, а скорее моё видение ситуации.  
Если у вас есть какие-то предложения или исправления в постановке задачи, также буду рад выслушать.

---

Пока что я вижу только решение "в лоб" с 4 запросами к БД на каждый пост, что выглядит не очень хорошо.

1. Запросить пост из таблицы постов,
2. Запросить пользователя по `author_id` из таблицы пользователей,
3. Отфильтровать комментарии по `id` поста из таблицы комментариев,
4. Запросить все вложения с `id` соответствующие массиву `id`-шников, перечисленных в посте из таблицы вложений.

Comment: Да, можно получить связанный набор данных одним запросом. Достаточно полистать документацию. Там даже [примеры](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx) именно с блогом. [Загрузка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx) связанных сущностей.

Comment: Если никто ответ не напишет, я попробую подробно расписать (может быть... потом...)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, немного запутался.. где-то вижу варианты с `Join`, а где-то с `Include` (я не только про ваши ссылки). И ещё, а что на счёт случая с вложениями, где нужно получить вложения с перечисленными `id`?

Comment: Если классы моделей созданы правильно, то лучше и проще использовать `Include`. Если нужные отношения в моделях не заданы, тогда вынужденно используем `Join`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, на сколько я понял, `Include` говорит EF, что надо загрузить всю коллекцию сразу в память. А есть вариант аля `IQuerable`, чтобы, к примеру, можно было использовать пагинацию для комментариев? Т.е. использовать что-то типо  `post.Comments.Skip(pageNum * pageSize).Take(pageSize);` и запрашивать комментарии из БД по-странично

Comment: Да, пагинация делается с помощью Skip/Take. [Why LINQ beats SQL](http://www.linqpad.net/WhyLINQBeatsSQL.aspx). Сходу не скажу, но наверняка можно и для вложенных сущностей применять.