# Пагинация с использованием ISpecification

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть сущность

```
public class Message : BaseEntity
{
    // some other fields
    public int[] AttachmentsIds { get; set; }
    public Attachment[] Attachments { get; set; } 
}
```

Планировалось, что первое поле будет браться из БД, потом по списку `Id` будет запрошены данные из другой таблицы и заполнено второе поле.

Для этого я думал написать репозитории для `Message` и `Attachments`, а затем сервис, который используя оба эти репозитория бы возвращал уже заполненную сущность `Message` или коллекцию сущностей.

Примерно так я представлял себе метод для получения всех сообщений с заполненными вложениями

```
public interface ISpecification<T>
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> Criteria { get; }
}
//...
IMessageRepository messageRep = ... ;
IAttachmentRepository attachmentRep = ... ;
//...
public IEnumerable<Message> GetMessagesWithAttachments(ISpecification<Message> spec)
{
    IEnumerable<Message> messages = messageRep.All.Where(spec.Criteria).ToList(); //All - IQueryble

    IEnumerable<int> attachmentsIds = messages.Select(m => m.AttachmentsIds).SelectMany(ids => ids).Distinct().ToList();
    IEnumerable<Attachments> attachments = attachmentRep.All.Where(id => attachmentsIds.Contains(id));

    foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        message.Attachments = attachmentsIds.Where(id => message.AttachmentsIds.Contains(id)).ToList();
    }

    return messages;
}
```

Запрашиваем все посты по фильтру, получаем список встреченных вложений, получаем его, а затем тасуем вложения по сообщениям.

Но если я хочу использовать пагинацию (или просто Skip и Take) или если мне необходимо сначала отсортировать, а потом сделать выборку, то непонятно как это сделать.

Решение в лоб, которое приходит в голову:

```
// модифицировать метод
public IEnumerable<Message> GetMessagesWithAttachments(IQueryble<Message> messages)
{
    IEnumerable<int> attachmentsIds = messages.Select(m => m.AttachmentsIds).SelectMany(ids => ids).Distinct().ToList();
    IEnumerable<Attachments> attachments = attachmentRep.All.Where(id => attachmentsIds.Contains(id));

    foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        message.Attachments = attachmentsIds.Where(id => message.AttachmentsIds.Contains(id)).ToList();
    }

    return messages;
}
//...
//и вызывать так:
IEnumerable<Message> messages = messageService.GetMessagesWithAttachments(
    messageService.All
        .OrderBy(...)
        .Where(...)
        .Skip(...)
        .Take(...)
);
```

Но решение не выглядит красивым и/или правильным =/

(Если есть советы по поводу самой архитектуры, то вот тут вопрос, на который ещё не ответили: [Строки одной таблицы как столбец в другой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837661) )

Comment: *Планировалось, что первое поле будет браться из БД, потом по списку Id будет запрошены данные из другой таблицы и заполнено второе поле.* — эээ, у вас EF? почему просто не воспользоваться штатными средствами ленивой загрузки?

Comment: Или, наоборот, жадной (с `.Include`)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а EF может взять массив id-шников и заполнить коллекцию?

Comment: Зачем вам коллекция id-шников?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну.. когда я думал над отображением многие ко многим через ещё одну таблицу `MessagesAttachments`, мне сказали, что это слишком медленный способ =/ поэтому я решил тогда хранить массив id вложений в столбце сообщения

Comment: Кто сказал и как аргументировал? EF умеет самостоятельно реализовывать связь многие-ко-многим, вручную создавать ту вспомогательную таблицу не нужно

Comment: @АндрейNOP аргументация была примерно такой: `много ключей, много данных, при разрастании данных сложные JOIN-ы будут работать всё медленнее`

Comment: ОК, а хранить массив id в столбце - это как? Без другой таблицы?

Comment: @АндрейNOP у этого человека не было опыта именно в ASP.Net Core, только в PHP. Так что при своей аргументации он не мог учитывать какие-то особенности EF. Просто других советчиков на тот момент у меня не было, а принцип БД, я полагал, что везде общий

Comment: @АндрейNOP, думал использовать PostgreSQL, которая умеет работать с массивами.

Comment: Очень сильно подозреваю, что нормальная связь по ключу будет работать гораздо быстрее, чем поле типа массива в таблице (ну и не факт, что EF умеет работать с такими полями). В общем пока выглядит как какая-то преждевременная оптимизация, причем оптимизируем путем гадания на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Давайте так: сейчас вы пишете так как описывают это во всех мануалах, а когда столкнетесь с проблемами производительности придете и спросите как улучшить производительность в конкретном примере с конкретными цифрами.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, спасибо за мнение. можно тогда спросить ещё про кое-что. тот же человек предложил мне объединить сущности постов и комментариев в одну общую и различать посты от комментариев по `initialId == null` (то есть, у сообщения нет владельца). Собственно, отсюда и появилась сущность `Message`, изначально у меня были отдельно посты и комментарии. Не могли бы вы посмотреть и этот вопрос и его тоже прокомментировать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837661/

Comment: @АндрейNOP, единственное, не обращайте внимание на attachments_ids в скриншоте, ибо вопрос создавался до ваших комментариев :)

Comment: *объединить сущности постов и комментариев в одну общую* — это еще зачем? У вас же между ними связь один-ко-многим. Я бы не стал, вот именно это как раз скорее всего приведет к проблемам с производительностью. Если нам не нужны в данный момент комментарии, зачем нам все их просматривать при поиске конкретного поста? Ну и вообще это денормализация же, какие-то избыточные столбцы появляются, которые будут где-то использоваться, а где-то – нет.

Comment: Прочтите вот это для начала: https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics Это относится к любым *реляционным* бд

Comment: @АндрейNOP, у меня всё ещё мало опыта работы с БД, так что спасибо за ваши советы и вашу ссылку.. прочитал.. сейчас буду переделывать :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, в итоге получилось следующее: https://pastebin.com/4HZgbxAs